# Radio button toggling not working in reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am developing the toggling radio button functionality in angular 7 using reactive forms. At the moment radio button is rendering for every  form array but  not toggling across the arrays. The user needs an ability to set one of the addresses as primary address. I have tried to assign new ids and value for the radio button but that has not made any difference

UI

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Code  - Update the code based on José Gazzano comments

```
<style>
    .desc-header {
        background-color: #FAE7D6;
        color: black
    }

    .header {
        width: 8%;
    }


    .panel-heading {
        color: white;
        background-color: #F59850;
        border-color: #ddd;
    }

    .col-form-label {
        padding: 0%;
    }

    .scrollClass {
        height: 500px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;


    }
</style>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        <span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Firm Details</span>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px;">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }"><input
                    type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="EditMode" class="hidden">Edit Mode</label>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

        <form [formGroup]="frmFirm" (ngSubmit)="saveManager()">
            <div *ngIf="FirmDetails && FirmDetails.Firm" class="card-body scrollClass">

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label modal-label header">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FirmDetails.Firm.NAME}}</div>
                        <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                            formControlName="NAME" />
                    </div>


                </div>
                <!-- 
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Short Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FirmDetails.Firm.SHORT_NAME}}</div>
                        <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                            formControlName="SHORT_NAME" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Alternate Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FirmDetails.Firm.ALTERNATE_NAME}}</div>
                        <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                            formControlName="ALTERNATE_NAME" />
                    </div>
                </div> -->

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label modal-label header">Date Founded</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{dateFoundedDate}}</div>
                        <kendo-datepicker *ngIf="EditMode" [format]="'MMMM yyyy'"
                            (valueChange)="dateFoundedChanged($event)" formControlName="DATE_FOUNDED"
                            class="form-control">
                        </kendo-datepicker>
                    </div>
                </div>




                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label modal-label header">Websites</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="inputEmail">Website URL</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="inputEmail">User Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="inputEmail">Password</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 offset-md-2">
                        <div formArrayName="Websites"
                            *ngFor="let item of frmFirm.get('Websites').controls; let i = index; let last = last">
                            <div [formGroupName]="i">

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input formControlName="WEBSITE_URL" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input formControlName="USERNAME" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input formControlName="PASSWORD" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1" *ngIf="EditMode">
                                        <button (click)="removeWebsite(i)">RM</button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row" *ngIf="EditMode">
                    <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-2">
                        <button type="button" (click)="addWebsite()">Add Website</button>
                    </div>
                </div>


                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="EditMode">
                        <button type="button" (click)="addAddress()">Add Address</button>
                    </div> -->



                <div formArrayName="Addresses" *ngFor="let item of frmFirm.get('Addresses').controls; let i = index;">

                    <div [formGroupName]="test">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label"> Primary Address
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" id="primary1Id{{i}}" type="radio" value="home{{i}}"
                                            formControlName="IS_HEAD_OFFICE"> Home
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label" attr.for="{{'street1Id' + i}}">Line 1
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input class="form-control" id="{{'street1Id' + i}}" type="text"
                                    formControlName="LINE1">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label" attr.for="{{'street2Id' + i}}">Line 2
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input class="form-control" id="{{'street2Id' + i}}" type="text"
                                    formControlName="LINE2">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label" attr.for="{{'street3Id' + i}}">Line 3
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input class="form-control" id="{{'street3Id' + i}}" type="text"
                                    formControlName="LINE3">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label" attr.for="{{'phoneId' + i}}">Phone
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input class="form-control" id="{{'phoneId' + i}}" type="text"
                                    formControlName="SWITCHBOARD_INT">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row" *ngIf="EditMode">

                            <div class="col-md-9 offset-md-2">
                                <button type="button" (click)="removeAddress(i)">Remove Address</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row " *ngIf="EditMode">
                    <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-2">
                        <button type="button" (click)="addAddress()">Add Address</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>





            <div class="btn-toolbar" style="padding-top:40px;">

                <span *ngIf="EditMode"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3">Save</button>

                </span>
                <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                        (click)="cancelManager">Cancel</button>
                </span>
                <span><button type="button" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all"
                        (click)="deleteManager()">Delete</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component

```
import { Component, Injectable, NgZone, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirmService } from '../services/firm.service';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { CommonDataService } from '../services/common.data.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { ListItem } from '../models/listItem';



@Component({
    selector: 'mgr-firm',
    templateUrl: './firm.component.html'
})
export class FirmComponent implements OnInit {
    private Error: string;
    public FirmDetails: any;
    public EditMode: boolean;
    public Editor = ClassicEditor;
    public EditorConfig: string;
    public originalContactList: any;
    public originalCityList: any;
    public events: string[] = [];
    @Input() FirmId: number;
    DateFoundedDate: Date;
    public frmFirm: FormGroup;
    public value: Date = new Date();



    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private firmService: FirmService, private commonDataService: CommonDataService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initializeFormModel();
        this.getFirmDetails();
    }


    initializeFormModel() {
        this.frmFirm = this._fb.group({
            NAME: [''],
            SHORT_NAME: [''],
            ALTERNATE_NAME: [''],
            DATE_FOUNDED: [''],

            HISTORY_HTML: [''],
            People: [''],
            Websites: this._fb.array([
                this.createWebsite()
            ]),
            Addresses: this._fb.array([
                this.createAddress()
            ])
        });
    }




    public addWebsite(): void {
        this.Websites.push(this.createWebsite());
    }



    public removeWebsite(index: number): void {
        const websites = this.frmFirm.get('Websites') as FormArray;
        if (websites.length === 1)
        {
            websites.reset();
          return;
        }
        websites.removeAt(index);
    }


    private createWebsite(): FormGroup {
        return this._fb.group({
            WEBSITE_URL: [''],
            USERNAME: [''],
            PASSWORD: ['']
        });
    }



    public addAddress(): void {
        this.Addresses.push(this.createAddress());
    }



    public removeAddress(index: number): void {
        const addressess = this.frmFirm.get('Addresses') as FormArray;
        if (addressess.length === 1)
        {
          addressess.reset();
          return;
        }
        addressess.removeAt(index);
    }

    private createAddress(): FormGroup {
        return this._fb.group({
            // city: [''],
            LINE1: [''],
            LINE2: [''],
            LINE3: [''],
            // zipCode: [''],
            SWITCHBOARD_INT: ['']
        });
    }



    get Websites(): FormArray {
        return <FormArray>this.frmFirm.get('Websites');
    }

    get Addresses(): FormArray {
        return <FormArray>this.frmFirm.get('Addresses');
    }


    get cities(): ListItem[] {
        return JSON.parse(this.FirmDetails.LongCitiesJson).map(x => new ListItem(x.CITY_ID, x.CITY_NAME, null));
    }


    setFormValues(FirmDetails: any) {
        this.frmFirm.patchValue({
            NAME: FirmDetails.Firm.NAME,
            SHORT_NAME: FirmDetails.Firm.SHORT_NAME,
            ALTERNATE_NAME: FirmDetails.Firm.ALTERNATE_NAME,
            DATE_FOUNDED: this.getDate(FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED),
            HISTORY_HTML: FirmDetails.Firm.HISTORY_HTML,
            People: FirmDetails.People

        });
      this.websites.patchValue(this.modifyFormGroupValues(FirmDetails.Websites, this.websitesMap))

     this.websites.patchValue(this.modifyFormGroupValues(FirmDetails.Websites, this.websitesMap)); 

     this.addressess.patchValue(this.modifyFormGroupValues(FirmDetails.Addresses,this.addressesMap))






        const addressGroup = FirmDetails.Firm.Addresses.map(address => {
            return this._fb.group({
                ID:    [address.ID],
                LINE1: [address.LINE1],
                LINE2:  [address.LINE2],
                LINE3:  [address.LINE3],
                SWITCHBOARD_INT:  [address.SWITCHBOARD_INT],
                IS_HEAD_OFFICE:  [address.IS_HEAD_OFFICE],
                CITY:  [address.CITY],
                CITY_ID:  [address.CITY_ID],
                POSTAL_CODE:  [address.POSTAL_CODE],
                FIRM_ID: [address.FIRM_ID]
            });
        });
        const addressFormArray: FormArray = this._fb.array(addressGroup);
        this.frmFirm.setControl('Addresses', addressFormArray);


        const websiteGroup = FirmDetails.Firm.Websites.map(website => {
           return this._fb.group({
            ID:    [website.ID],
            WEBSITE_URL: [website.WEBSITE_URL],
            USERNAME:   [website.USERNAME],
            PASSWORD:   [website.PASSWORD],
            FIRM_ID: [website.FIRM_ID]
            });
        });
        const wesbiteFormArray: FormArray = this._fb.array(websiteGroup);
        this.frmFirm.setControl('Websites', wesbiteFormArray);
    }

    getFirmDetails() {
        if (this.FirmId != null) {
            this.firmService.getFirmDetails(this.FirmId)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.FirmDetails = data;
                    this.originalContactList = this.FirmDetails.People;
                    this.originalCityList = JSON.parse(this.FirmDetails.LongCitiesJson);
                    this.setFormValues(this.FirmDetails);
                },
                    err => {
                        this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
                    },
                    () => {
                    });
        }
    }

    get dateFoundedDate(): string {
        if (this.FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED != null) {
        const dateString = this.FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED;
        const results = parseInt(dateString.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)[^+]\//i, "$1"));
        const date = new Date(results);
        const month = date.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long' });
        return (month + '-' + date.getFullYear());
        }
    }

    private getDate(dateFounded: string): Date {
        if (dateFounded != null) {
        const results = parseInt(dateFounded.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)[^+]\//i, "$1"));
        const date = new Date(results);
        return new Date(date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate());
        }
    }

    saveManager() {

        const result = Object.assign(this.FirmDetails.Firm, this.frmFirm.value);
        //this.FirmDetails.Firm = Object.assign({}, result.Firm);


        //const firm = {...this.FirmDetails.Firm, ...this.frmFirm.value};
        this.firmService.createFirm(this.FirmDetails)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.getFirmDetails();
                this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
            },
                err => {
                    this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
                },
                () => {
                });
    }

    public keyContactChange(value: any): void {
        this.FirmDetails.Firm.KEY_CONTACT_ID = value;
    }

    public dateFoundedChanged(value: Date): void {
        this.FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED = value;
    }


    handleFilter(value) {
        if (value.length >= 1) {
            this.FirmDetails.People = this.originalContactList.filter((s) => s.FIRST_NAME.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
        } else {
            this.FirmDetails.People = this.originalContactList;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you please give a minimum reproduction on stackblitz

Answer (score 3):

you set formControlName in the correct way, now just give a unic ID to each one of the radio buttons.

**Edit:**
plus you didn't closed your input tag. 
I changed from `<input type....> to <input type.../>`

One more big tip:
When you are working with Angular, you should divide your html to much smaller components.
your html file is way too long then it should be.
for example your four group should be a single component that made from smaller one's as the input+label for example. the smaller component must receive  all of the input that it's need for working with forms.
you can read more about how to do it [in here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-component-design-how-to-avoid-custom-event-bubbling-and-extraneous-properties-in-the-local-component-tree/)

```
             <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label"> Primary Address   </label>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                      <div class="form-check">
                          <label class="form-check-label">
                              <input class="form-check-input" id="primary1Id{{i}}" type="radio" value="home{{i}}"
                                  formControlName="IS_HEAD_OFFICE"/> <span>Home</span>
                          </label>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: I guess this is the only change that your a referring to primary1Id{{i}} for radio button control. I tried it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Tom please edit your question and upload the full html+TS so I will be able to simulate it on my own machine

Comment: Were you able to spot the issue ?

Answer (score 3):

the problem here is that your radio buttons have the same value assigned, so they are treated as the same input. That's why you can't toggle between them.

Try setting a different value for each of them and it should be working as expected and this will also help with your form logic and validations ;)

As a reminder, the only thing you need in order to make a group of radio buttons to toggle between them is setting the same name (or formControlName in your case) to all of them, and of course also different values. **Do not** set the same Id as it was previously suggested because that's not semantically correct from an HTML perspective

Here's a minimal StackBlitz example where you can try it out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lvahzg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

It has all the radio buttons with the same formContrlName and the same value, try setting different values to each of them and see how it works ;)

Edit: Adding Angular documentation regarding radio buttons withing reactive forms https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor

Edit 2: Here's the issue I was talking on my comment

```
<div formArrayName="Addresses" *ngFor="let item of frmFirm.get('Addresses').controls; let i = index;">

  <div [formGroupName]="i"> --> This formGroupName should be the same on each loop in order to make the radio buttons to toggle between them

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label"> Primary Address
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" id="primary1Id{{i}}" type="radio" value="home{{i}}"
                                            formControlName="IS_HEAD_OFFICE"> Home
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Hi jose what you shared is a simple scenario. I tried providing different values. Not sure if the way i have done is right. Please find the updated code. However it is not yet working for me

Comment: Hi @Tom I noticed another issue, your radio buttons are assigned to different forms.

If you take close attention to your ngFor you're setting a different formGroupName on each iteration, and on each iteration defining the radio buttons. Since they're inside elements with different formGroupName, the reactive forms directive from angular treats them as different elements and so the value isn't toggling as expected.

Try setting the same formGroupName on the form that contains the addresses.

I'll update my original answer with this

Comment: Hey Jose, I have updated the html bit on the post. I have given the same formGroupName as Test but that doesnt seem to make any difference

Comment: Were you able to spot the issue ?

Comment: Hey @Tom I couldn't get to replicate that. But I'll try again if I manage to get some spare time. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your requirements is when a user sets an address as "Home" all of the other addresses should be **unset** as "Home." If my understanding is correct, You were on the right track with your original code but there are a couple of things that you will need to correct.

#### Form Group Name

With the ngFor you are creating an address for each control that is in the FormArray. Each control in the FormArray is a FormGroup whos name is its index in the FormArray. So you were correct when you had i has the formGroupName

So change back to this

```
<div [formGroupName]="i">
```

#### Create an OnPrimaryToggleMethod

Add a method to the component that will set IS_HEAD_OFFICE to false for every other control in the array

```
onPrimaryToggled(newValue: any, changedItem: FormControl) {
  if (newValue.returnValue === true) {
  const toChange = this.frmFirm.get('Addresses').controls.filter(el => el !== changedItem);
    toChange.forEach(el => el.patchValue({
      IS_HEAD_OFFICE: false
    }));
  }
}
```

#### Update the checkbox to call the toggle method

Add a change event binding to the the radio button to call the method

```
(change)="onPrimaryToggled($event, item)"
```

Now it should look like the below code (btw, you don't need the value attribute)

```
<div formArrayName="Addresses" *ngFor="let item of frmFirm.get('Addresses').controls; let i = index;">
     <div [formGroupName]="i">
           <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label"> Primary Address </label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                   <div class="form-check">
                      <label class="form-check-label">

                        <input
                            class="form-check-input" 
                            id="primary1Id{{i}}" 
                            type="radio" 
                            formControlName="IS_HEAD_OFFICE" 
                            (change)="OnPrimaryToggled($event, item)"
                        > Home

                      </label>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             </div>                        
      </div>
</div>
```